# query failing on a database, but works fine after backup is restored

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I faced for the first time this problem:
1) on a production database a query takes forever to complete
2) i take backup of database, restore it on my laptop to debug: the query works fine, and returns in 1 second

My gut feeling is that something is corrupted (like indexes), this never happened to me so i am just guessing.

Could you please suggest a way to check for this kind of errors?

Just for reference i paste here the query, but it makes not much sense.

In the production db if i completely remove the subquery after CROSS APPLY the query executes fine:

```
SELECT
  CA.ID_CESPITE,  CASE WHEN child.count > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS HAVE_CHILD_PRG,
  CA.ID_CESPITE_PADRE,
      CA.ID_TIPO_CESPITE,
      CA.COD_CESPITE,
      CA.DESCR_CESPITE,
      CA.ID_STATO_CESPITE,
      CA.ID_REFERENTE, 
      VUD.ID_UTENTE AS ID_UTENTE_RESPONSABILE,VUD.ID_DIPENDENTE,
      ISNULL(CP.V, 'N') AS V,
      ISNULL(CP.O, 'N') AS O,
      ISNULL(CP.I, 'N') AS I,
      ISNULL(CP.A, 'N') AS A,
      CTCS.ID_TIPO_CESPITE AS ID_TIPO_CES, 0 AS LEVELO,
      CA.PROF_ID,CA.ISLOCKED,CTCS.DESCR_TIPO_CESPITE
FROM
  CES_ANAGRAFICA CA LEFT OUTER JOIN CES_PERMESSI CP  ON ((CA.ID_CESPITE = CP.ID_CESPITE) AND (CP.ID_UTENTE = 4654 ))
 LEFT JOIN CES_TIPI_CESPITE CTCS  ON CA.ID_TIPO_CESPITE = CTCS.ID_TIPI_INFRSTR
LEFT OUTER JOIN V_UTENTI_DIPENDENTI VUD  ON CA.ID_RESPONSABILE = VUD.ID_DIPENDENTE 
CROSS APPLY (  SELECT [Count] = COUNT(*)  FROM V_CESPITE_TREE VCA  JOIN MAN_PRG_OPERAZIONI MPO
    ON MPO.ID_CESPITE = VCA.ID_CHILD  WHERE VCA.ID_PARENT = CA.ID_CESPITE AND MPO.ID_FATHER is not null) child
```

I was ready to find the issue working on my laptop but i was surprised that after restoring the backup (to a new test database) all worked as expected.

I hope i expressed myself.

Comment: Check what it is waiting on and whether it is blocked. While the query is running, in another window: `SELECT wait_type, status, blocking_session_id FROM sys.dm_exec_requests;` for that session_id.

Comment: Does your production server's maintenance plan include updating statistics? It may be that SQL is optimizing your query based on stale heuristics.

Comment: i thank you for the ideas, but the final decision was to restore the backup on a new installation od sql server to solve the issue quickly. I am sorry because i was not able to understand what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you have given, its mostly the problem with query(execution) plan and commonly referred as parameter sniffing. Check this [here](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/)

While execution plans are there to speed up queries but some same plan may not be good for 2 different scenarios. When u are restoring and executing on other system there is no query plan for that instance so it is creating new plan and execution is quick. So try to clear ur cache and execute once again... if it executes quickly then it is for sure problem of parameter sniffing. But there is no one go to fix for this problem... go to above link you may find an appropriate solution.

Comment: thanks for the pointer, in my case it is mountain and mouse, not elephant and mouse.